# return multiple different values based on 2 criteria in excel

Tags: excel

Hope you can help. I have 2 excel sheets that look like this:

```
Sheet1:

 ID       trnx       Module
 1        aj08       AA
 2        aj08       AA
 3        aj08       AA
 1        CJ20       ps opex
 1        CJ20       ps capex
 2        cn22       HR

 Sheet 2

 ID       trnx       Module
 1        aj08 
 2        aj08 
 1        ml81
 3        aj08
 2        cn22
 1        cj20
 1        cj20
 3        mm02
```

The formula im using is

```
INDEX($G$2:$G$9,SMALL(IF(A2=$F$2:$F$9,ROW($F$2:$F$9)-MIN(ROW($F$2:$F$9))+1,"")&IF(C2=$H$2:$H$9,ROW($H$2:$H$9)-MIN(ROW($H$2:$H$9))+1,""),COUNTIF(A$2:A$2,A2)&COUNTIF(C$2:C$2,C2)))
```

I need "module" from sheet 2 to be populated based on matching ID and trnx, and if the ID matches but not the trnx, then it must that cell for module to "No Match".

The problem i am experiencing is that sheet 2 is populating the data incorrectly. For Example the second occurrence of ID "1" in sheet 2 is pulling out Module ps opex. it is suppose to be "No Match" since the trnx in sheet 2 is ml81.

please help!!! Thanks in advance:)

Comment: We need to know how you are actually pulling out your data to help you. Is it a VBA procedure ? Is it an Excel function ? If so, what is the exact function (paste the whole thing here). We can't help you if we have to guess.

Comment: Thanks Alexandre. See i have updated the question. It is an excel function.

Comment: you have two rows with the pair `(1, cj20)` with different module results, and two duplicate entries in sheet 2 with the same pair. Is there any other rule that says that one of those rows is `ps opex` and the other is `ps capex`? Would it be appropriate to merge those rows? or add some additional Id?

Comment: I think you're overthinking this. Make a 4th column which is the concatenation of ID and trnx on both sheets then use either VLOOKUP, INDEX/MATCH or whatever you fancy to retrieve the module that matches that combination. Your formula is a bit overkill in my opinion.

Answer (score 0):

This won't address the part I asked in my comment where you have 'duplicate keys' but may help you anyway :

Since your key is really the combination of the `Id` and the `trnx` columns, I inserted a concatenated column (I used `=CONCATENATE(trnx, "_", id)` where those names refer to sheet locations, but you could just as readily concatenate in the other direction as well, or use some other delimiter. It's just to make a single key column (that we can sort on and search more easily.)

In sheet 2 I form the same key column from the values listed there, and then your module column becomes :

```
 =IF(ISNA(VLOOKUP(I12,$C$10:$D$15,2,0)), "No Match", VLOOKUP(I12,$C$10:$D$15,2,0))
```

Where in that formula, I12 is the key cell we are looking up in sheet 2, and the absolute reference in the VLOOKUP is the data table in sheet 1.